# C++ Inheritance and Pthreads with Virtual Worker Functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, pthreads, virtual

I have a class that I'm trying to implement as an abstract class to maximize code reuse.  However, a major part of the commonality between the two derived classes lies in the fact that each has a consumer and producer thread.  I'm wondering if I can have each static member function call a virtual member function that does all of the underlying work.

Basically, is the following code allowed or am I doing something super hacky, or will the compiler yell/scream at me?

```
// in AbstractClass.h
class AbstractClass {
  // some code here including constructors/destructors
 protected:
  virtual int Worker() = 0;  // derived class provides implementation
 private:
  static void* Thread(void* args);
};

// in AbstractClass.cpp
static void* AbstractClass::Thread(void* args) {
  AbstractClass myobject = static_cast<AbstractClass*>(args);
  myobject->Worker();
}
```

Basically I'm wondering if the derived class "worker" will ever be called this way?  Note that p_thread_create() is called with passing in the Thread() function.

Thanks for the help as I try to improve my understanding of inheritance and virtual functions and how I can use it to maximize code reuse.

Comment: The compiler will not yell, it will see the static cast and assume you know what you are doing. Consider using C++11 threads which are more type safe.

Comment: @n.m. I'm getting there, I promise!  I just want to use p_threads for the time being since I want to get a good grasp of the underlying magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the code looks fine and your assumptions are correct. The purpose of virtual functions is that the most derived version of a function will be called no matter which superclass signature the method is called on.

Using pthreads and C++, the approach you are using is perfectly reasonable and not hackey. However, I would create the threads in a separate class which would contain the static class method. This would stop the threads from being mixed up in your derived classes.

```
struct ThreadManager
{
  ThreadManager(AbstractWorker* worker)
  {
     mWorker = worker;
     mThread = ThreadStart(threadFunc, this); /* made up thread code :) */
  }
  ~ThreadManager()
  {
     ThreadStop(mThread);
  }

  static void* threadFunc(void* args)
  {
     ThreadManager* manager = static_cast<ThreadManager*>(args);
     manager->mWorker->Work();
  }

  AbstractWorker* mWorker;
  Thread mThread;
}
```

Note that when using pthreads a static function is actually required.

Comment: That's my conundrum... if I create the threads in the derived class, I'm losing a good percentage of the code that will be shared between derived classes.  Thus, I really lose the rationale to have an abstract class.

Comment: @It'sPete i will illustrate. - answer changed - make a separate concrete object which uses the abstract interface.

Comment: @It'sPete BTW you may not have realized it, but the static function is actually required by pthreads. You cannot have a normal function pointer to a virtual function and expect it to work like a virtual function.